# Difference in current time between iOS and Android simulators

Tags: android, swift, kotlin, ios-simulator, android-virtual-device

It looks like there's a small difference (milliseconds) when getting the current time in iOS and Android.

Swift: `Date().toMillis()`

Kotlin: `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Check the following example (left is iOS, right is Android):

[image]

The current timestamp in iOS (first message sent) is `1595158104237`, while the current timestamp in Android (second message sent) is `1595158098388`, with the Android one being 5849ms earlier than the iOS one even if it was sent later.

Is that something that can only happen in emulators, or also in real devices?

Is there a way to get the "same" current timestamp on both systems?

Answer (score 0):

Because it local device timestamp, if you change system date in the device it will change the timestamp as well

If you want, you can get timestamp from a server so it will be same for all device and OS

Comment: I understand that it is the local device timestamp, my question is why the timestamp in Android (having both iOS and Android set to the same timezone) is 5 seconds "smaller" than the iOS one.

Comment: I assume you set it to automatic date&time, I don't know where android and ios get their automatic date&time, it's might because android and ios get automatic date&time from a different source